# VS Code TypeScript auto import suggestion priority

Tags: visual-studio-code

Let's say in my React project (TS if that matters), I have a custom `components` module that exports a component called `Button`. I also have a third party library in `node_modules` that also exports a component called `Button`. Is there a way to tell VS Code to prioritize my own module over those in `node_modules` for auto-import - i.e. I want my own modules to show up at the top of the import suggestion list rather than the third party `node_modules` ones if I type JSX like `<Button`.

Comment: another question about sorting typescript suggestions: [TypeScript React props priority when using IntelliSense in VS Code](/q/68686383/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

*Apparently* (if I am understanding what I'm reading correctly), this is supposed to be how it works, and it regressed at some point, but got fixed (emphasis on "apparently"). See [Prefer local auto-imports over those from external modules #42104](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42104) and [Matt Bierner's last comment there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42104#issuecomment-475459279):

> I believe this was fixed at some point (possible a duplicate of [microsoft/TypeScript#23598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23598))

If that's the case, if you're still getting this issue, it could be a regression, in which case it might be appropriate to raise a new issue ticket (make sure to include version numbers for everything relevant, and provide instructions to reproduce the issue).

---

You might also be interested in this TypeScript feature-request issue ticket: [Auto-import priority rules #51155](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51155), which is more broad and makes the following suggestion:

> - code found within the repo/module (preferring aliased paths if they exist, probably preferring "closer" imports over further away in the tree?)
> - code found in other repos/modules defined locally within a monorepo (again preferring aliases)
> - code found in explicit dependencies found in package.json
> - code found in node internals (ex: fs, path)

You can give it a thumbs up to show support for it and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. But please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

[Someone commented in the issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51155#issuecomment-1955317661) that you can change the order of suggestions from the builtin TypeScript Language Support extension for VS Code by using a TypeScript plugin, which they made a repo for [here](https://github.com/tidalhq/ts-plugin-sort-import-suggestions) (I have no affiliation with that repo or person)

---

For your reference / learning purposes, I found those issue tickets by googling "`github typescript OR vscode issues import suggestion order`" and clicking through related issue tickets.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.