# Change Auto-Import Priority Order In VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-import

I'm working on a Next-JS project with TypeScript.
Everything was fine till one day, VSCode decided to change my auto-import priorty.
In my case, I wanted to import `useEffect`, `useContext`,.. from `react`. But somehow, Vscode auto-import first-place changed to `preact-hook`, which is different from `react` and take me time to debug it later when I test the code.

[image: Example:]

Any Idea how can I change the order to let react goes first?

Comment: I've noticed since the last update (or maybe I installed some extensions?) that my imports were working like a dream, and now it cannot seem to figure out simple imports like `<Image` auto-completing & auto-importing from `next/image`. This may be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69038328/why-is-vs-code-importing-from-hoist-non-react-statics-node-modules-types-react

Comment: I had exact same issue with ```next/image``` and ```next/link```

Comment: seems to be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/63251182/11107541